# fetching data from same table in multiple join hierarchy

Tags: sql, join, mariadb, hierarchy

I have a project with users, placed in some kind of hierarchy tree. a user can have multiple children and multiple parents. the organization chart looks like this :

[image]

this hierarchy uses 2 tables in database, `user` and `position`. here is the SQL to reproduce the tables with few fixtures to reproduce the organization image provided below:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Hôte : db
-- Généré le :  jeu. 24 mai 2018 à 07:39
-- Version du serveur :  10.2.14-MariaDB-10.2.14+maria~jessie
-- Version de PHP :  7.2.4

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `hierarchy` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `hierarchy`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `position`;
CREATE TABLE `position` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uuid` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:guid)',
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `position` (`id`, `user_id`, `parent_id`, `uuid`, `type`) VALUES
(2, 3, NULL, '7db54d6a-6a89-3fe2-87ba-c0dd96d4f664', 'TYPE_HR_PLUS'),
(3, 4, 3, 'adadab97-c0b8-3f89-a245-4edb077a4579', 'TYPE_HR_PLUS'),
(4, 5, 3, '4efec484-8a1f-3c27-a48f-a8c8412e18db', 'TYPE_HR_PLUS'),
(5, 6, 4, '8027b0cb-3e34-357a-8bff-80e4abbf60ef', 'TYPE_HR_PLUS'),
(6, 7, 4, 'e588ec20-9b0e-3ec6-8164-bdfafdf4b440', 'TYPE_HR'),
(7, 8, 5, '61e537d7-5ed6-36b3-8969-1913cdacb42b', 'TYPE_HR'),
(8, 9, 5, '6c241f8f-1a0a-34dc-8042-591352a764ea', 'TYPE_HR_PLUS'),
(9, 9, 3, 'e03998c4-d95a-3410-9727-099f0c83b3d5', 'TYPE_COLLABORATOR'),
(10, 10, 6, '67de2883-a7b0-3260-bb2a-67d3ffa3dc40', 'TYPE_HR'),
(11, 11, 7, '07d37612-01bf-3eec-b249-41c20d756144', 'TYPE_COLLABORATOR'),
(12, 11, 5, '09f7f6f1-59e2-37c0-a2e4-ae9b58ba6c93', 'TYPE_HR'),
(13, 12, 9, '724b8185-b6eb-3d35-b71f-1d076b3020ed', 'TYPE_HR'),
(14, 13, 9, '97d90e5c-7872-3e1e-be65-0f6b5329f54c', 'TYPE_HR_PLUS'),
(15, 14, 10, '3c357b9d-e162-316b-921c-25157d523e70', 'TYPE_COLLABORATOR'),
(16, 14, 3, '542235c6-462c-4922-a629-303430701000', 'TYPE_COLLABORATOR'),
(17, 15, 10, '2d208936-a7e9-32c1-963f-0df7f57ae463', 'TYPE_COLLABORATOR'),
(18, 16, 11, '00b678a2-54cd-3f37-9381-0cd92acea079', 'TYPE_COLLABORATOR'),
(19, 17, 8, 'ec4b8cad-fbce-3692-8d4c-f48f7ffa6452', 'TYPE_COLLABORATOR'),
(20, 18, 12, '48f0c85c-3801-3275-8978-5b2573fd7e0b', 'TYPE_COLLABORATOR'),
(21, 18, 10, 'd6129dec-8823-3304-8dfe-819118073d1f', 'TYPE_COLLABORATOR'),
(22, 19, 13, '1ec9c202-97d7-3311-9119-f6e9f55d058b', 'TYPE_COLLABORATOR'),
(23, 20, 9, '3ab32120-520b-3d41-80f0-56fd3876eecb', 'TYPE_COLLABORATOR');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uuid` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:guid)',
  `first_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `uuid`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
(3, 'fb7304f6-5ade-4c06-83e5-36827a4d7904', 'Albus', 'Dumbledore'),
(4, '60af55ca-e9cd-3d8a-bc8a-c9f7ec99baa1', 'Minerva', 'McGonagall'),
(5, 'a422b364-b68f-324b-8836-d38ca62001f5', 'Severus', 'Rogue'),
(6, 'cbdf94a8-f4e3-360b-ba7f-10ea7e59b85d', 'Filius', 'Flitwick'),
(7, '9bce88c9-7b7d-3db3-8780-b6397bb1263d', 'Remus', 'Lupin'),
(8, 'b9d85cfa-3c46-33c1-8750-53be1c281111', 'Pomona', 'Chourave'),
(9, 'c07d10d7-333f-327a-ab32-201209127b7a', 'Rolanda', 'Bibine'),
(10, '8a7b76a1-5f0c-31ff-a93a-ca478598682b', 'Gilderoy', 'Lockhart'),
(11, '7302700a-0bc5-3ed0-84fc-857e975a5771', 'Alastor', 'Maugrey'),
(12, '7b8722f3-1570-3351-864a-ede9ee3a90e6', 'Sybille', 'Trelawney'),
(13, '12a7683a-00da-46a6-b7fd-a6eae5b10e3c', 'Dolores', 'Ombrage'),
(14, 'f054bdeb-a8b8-41e5-be78-b00d1b9377f3', 'Harry', 'Potter'),
(15, 'b1f696ad-cfa3-3830-8685-c45ff4a4ffda', 'Ronald', 'Weasley'),
(16, '8b2a64e9-ed28-363d-a731-3e15e255cd1d', 'Hermione', 'Granger'),
(17, 'f6aa74f9-2a4a-346d-bf75-3f8b02614c19', 'Neville', 'Londubat'),
(18, '8fbbc431-2555-3718-8055-ad8637260732', 'Drago', 'Malefoy'),
(19, '78a58546-8ae1-330d-9426-c23c74b71e78', 'Luna', 'Lovegood'),
(20, '4739a44b-d1b7-3390-9bbb-cbd2e39b4ec0', 'Ginny', 'Weasley');

ALTER TABLE `position`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `uuid_idx` (`uuid`),
  ADD KEY `IDX_462CE4F5727ACA70` (`parent_id`),
  ADD KEY `IDX_462CE4F5A76ED395` (`user_id`);

ALTER TABLE `user`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `uuid_idx` (`uuid`);

ALTER TABLE `position`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1024;

ALTER TABLE `user`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1027;

ALTER TABLE `position`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_462CE4F5727ACA70` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_462CE4F5A76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`);


COMMIT;
```

One important thing to notice is the `position` table represents a relation between a user and its parent, and it also stores a string defining the relation type (actually it represents the user type of the child in this relation).

EDIT : one really important thing I didn't mention yet is there is no recursivity in this tree, there can be only a maximum number of 5 levels, as shown in the organization image: 1 HR_PLUS Head of Department, followed by maximum 3 levels of HR_PLUS or HR, followed by 1 level of COLLAB

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

For a given `position` uuid, i'd like to fetch every child user below this relation.

For example, the relation between Minerva McGonagall and Albus Dumbledore is the position #3 with uuid `adadab97-c0b8-3f89-a245-4edb077a4579`. Given this uuid, i'd like to fetch every user below Minerva McGonagall:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| id    | first_name    | last_name     |
+---------------------------------------+
| 6     | Filius        | Flitwick      |
| 7     | Remus         | Lupin         |
| 10    | Gilderoy      | Lockhart      |
| 11    | Alastor       | Maugrey       |
| 14    | Harry         | Potter        |
| 15    | Ronald        | Weasley       |
| 16    | Hermione      | Granger       |
| 18    | Drago         | Malefoy       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

The query I wrote so far is the following:

```
SELECT u2.id, u2.first_name, u2.last_name 
FROM `user` u1 

JOIN position p1 ON p1.user_id = u1.id
JOIN position p2 ON p2.parent_id = p1.user_id
JOIN user u2 ON u2.id = p2.user_id

WHERE p1.uuid = 'adadab97-c0b8-3f89-a245-4edb077a4579'
AND p1.type IN ('TYPE_HR', 'TYPE_HR_PLUS')
```

I added a filter on `type` property  because I don't want the query to return anything if `type` is not `HR` or `HR_PLUS`.
Right now, the query returns the users directly below Minerva McGonagall (Filius and Remus). And I can't figure how to return the rest of the users below them.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

I just succeed in fetch the expected data using a `UNION`, as this is not a recursive tree:

```
SELECT u2.id, u2.first_name, u2.last_name 
FROM `user` u1 

JOIN position p1 ON p1.user_id = u1.id
JOIN position p2 ON p2.parent_id = p1.user_id
JOIN user u2 ON u2.id = p2.user_id

WHERE p1.uuid = 'adadab97-c0b8-3f89-a245-4edb077a4579'
AND p1.type IN ('TYPE_HR', 'TYPE_HR_PLUS')

UNION

SELECT u2.id, u2.first_name, u2.last_name 
FROM `user` u1 

JOIN position p1 ON p1.user_id = u1.id
JOIN position p2 ON p2.parent_id = p1.user_id
JOIN position p3 ON p3.parent_id = p2.user_id
JOIN user u2 ON u2.id = p3.user_id

WHERE p1.uuid = 'adadab97-c0b8-3f89-a245-4edb077a4579'
AND p1.type IN ('TYPE_HR', 'TYPE_HR_PLUS')

UNION

SELECT u2.id, u2.first_name, u2.last_name 
FROM `user` u1 

JOIN position p1 ON p1.user_id = u1.id
JOIN position p2 ON p2.parent_id = p1.user_id
JOIN position p3 ON p3.parent_id = p2.user_id
JOIN position p4 ON p4.parent_id = p3.user_id
JOIN user u2 ON u2.id = p4.user_id

WHERE p1.uuid = 'adadab97-c0b8-3f89-a245-4edb077a4579'
AND p1.type IN ('TYPE_HR', 'TYPE_HR_PLUS')
```

but this looks very heavy , and i'm pretty sure there is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: This is not very easy. A general solution that would satisfy any amount of data in your tables is essentially a tree traversal algorithm, and needs a looping structure. Using a cursor or a while loop seems hardly avoidable.

Comment: Add the tag os the sql language you are using, too

Comment: one really important thing I didn't mention is there is no recursivity in this tree, there can be only a maximum number of 5 levels, as shown in the organization image: 1 HR_PLUS Head of Department, followed by maximum 3 levels of HR_PLUS or HR, followed by 1 level of COLLAB

Comment: Note that u1 is actually not needed in your queries. Save one join ;)

Comment: I'm not a MariaDB person, but in SQL Server we'd solve this sort of issue using a recursive CTE.  It looks like MariaDB supports something similar: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already found the union solution, here's an alternative using a loop (And pseudocode):

Create a table to hold your results, lets call it r.

```
Insert into r the results of your first query, along with a field named level with a value of 1.
set i=2
while (at least a line of r exists where level=i-1) do the following:
insert into r (level=i)
   a modification of your select based on selecting positions from r 
   where level=i-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=21070de84047495d0599cfe2c9fe82b2)

```
with recursive cte as (
  select `user_id` as `ancestor_id`
  /* , 0 as `degreesOfSeperation` */
  , `user_id` 
  from `position`
  union all
  select c.`ancestor_id` 
  /* , c.`degreesOfSeperation` + 1 */
  , p.`user_id` 
  from `cte` as c
  inner join `position` as p
  on p.`parent_id` = c.`user_id`
)
select u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name
from cte c
inner join `user` a on a.`id` = c.`ancestor_id`
inner join `position` p on p.`user_id` = a.`id`
inner join `user` u on u.`id` = c.`user_id`
/* WHERE c.`degreesOfSeperation` > 0 */
WHERE c.`user_id` != c.`ancestor_id` 
AND p.`uuid` = 'adadab97-c0b8-3f89-a245-4edb077a4579'
AND p.`type` IN ('TYPE_HR', 'TYPE_HR_PLUS')
order by c.`degreesOfSeperation`
;
```

Output

id first_name last_name

```
Id | First_Name | Last_Name
---+------------+----------  
 6 | Filius     | Flitwick 
 7 | Remus      | Lupin 
10 | Gilderoy   | Lockhart 
11 | Alastor    | Maugrey 
18 | Drago      | Malefoy 
14 | Harry      | Potter 
15 | Ronald     | Weasley 
16 | Hermione   | Granger
```

Most of this is likely already already familiar to you.
The logic to deal with the hierarchical structure is the `recursive cte`.
This has 2 parts:

Part 1

select `user_id` as `ancestor_id`
  , 0 as `degreesOfSeperation`
  , `user_id` 
  from `position`

This gets all users from the position table, setting their record as the `ancestor` record; i.e. the root from which we'll grow our tree.  We set degreesOfSeperation to 0 to state that this is the root record; i.e. the one where the user and the ancestor are one and the same.

Part 2

```
  select c.`ancestor_id` 
  , c.`degreesOfSeperation` + 1
  , p.`user_id` 
  from `cte` as c
  inner join `position` as p
  on p.`parent_id` = c.`user_id`
```

This is the recursive part; for each user added to the tree already (i.e. from the root statement; or from the last iteration of populating the cte table) we now fetch any other positions for which the position's parents match the previous iteration's user. We add one to the `degreesOfSeparation` so we can tell how far away from the root ancestor this record is.

`DegressOfSeparation` is not actually required (in fact, in the above statement I've commented this out); but I tend to include it since it's useful for debugging / seeing what's going on.  Here's what the `cte` looks like without any filters, to help you understand what's going on:

```
With recursive cte as (
  select `user_id` as `ancestor_id`
  , 0 as `degreesOfSeperation`
  , `user_id` 
  from `position`
  union all
  select c.`ancestor_id` 
  , c.`degreesOfSeperation` + 1
  , p.`user_id` 
  from `cte` as c
  inner join `position` as p
  on p.`parent_id` = c.`user_id`
)
select *
from cte c
order by c.`ancestor_id`
, c.`degreesOfSeperation`
, c.`user_id`
;
```

[Results here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=26070829b4f0184ad244d155582b797f)